# Using an ES6 module to perform initialization

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a good pattern to run code that runs only once for initialization.

using `import viewInitializer from './viewInitializer';`

feels a bit wrong because I am left with a useless variable and I am importing something that doesn't need importation.

Comment: I don't think you've really given enough info. If it is run once, fine, but it could go in any of your existing modules, why would it need to be in it's own? If it does, `import './viewInitializer';` also works without importing a variable.

Comment: put it for a correct answer but I just felt import doesn't feel very intuitive. but yes, I just like parts of the code that run once to be in other files scattered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is works the similar to classic node.js `require` function. If you don't need a value from import, you can just omit it.

```
import './viewInitializer';
```

Compare with code which initialises Babel in node.js

```
require("babel/register");
```